# Elastic search random script query not getting back any results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch random documents from the elastic search index. I tried this query but it's not working:

```
{
  "query" : { "query_string" : {"query" : "*:*"} },
  "sort" : {
    "_script" : { 
        "script" : "(doc['_id'].value + salt).hashCode()",
        "type" : "number",
        "params" : {
            "salt" : "32423"
        },
        "order" : "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove "sort" from this and run following query, it returns back the documents:

```
{
  "query" : { "query_string" : {"query" : "*:*"} }
}
```

Is there any error in 1st query with "sort" script? How can i debug such queries?

We are using latest elastic search version and "_id" is string  i.e. "X2345".

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Elasticsearch 6.x.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "query":"*:*"
      },
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "_script":{  
                  "script":"(doc['_id'].value + salt).hashCode()",
                  "type":"number",
                  "params":{  
                     "salt":"32423"
                  },
                  "order":"asc"
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   }
}
```